# SVG shape distortion with FeTurbulences

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, svg-filters, distortion

My question is quite simple : Is it possible to reproduce [this effect](https://graphism.fr) (the circle distortion animation) with SVG filters ?

I think it would be interesting to use FeTurbulences with FeDisplacementMap because it works on a [static way](http://codepen.io/vavouweb/pen/yMemoO). But actually, I don't which attribute I should tween to make the animation nice.

```
<feTurbulence type="fractalNoise" baseFrequency="0.01" numOctaves="2" result="warp" seed="0" stichTitles="stitch"></feTurbulence>
<feDisplacementMap xChannelSelector="R" yChannelSelector="G" scale="30" in="SourceGraphic" in2="warp" />
```

If you have other solutions (js libraries, filters, etc) : please don't hesitate. I'm open to every solutions ;)

Thank you for your consideration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how you do that kind of filter. The baseFrequency controls the granularity of the distortion, the scale controls the size of the displacement and the dur in the Animate controls the speed. I've animated the scale and added a shadow to match the original a bit better.

```html
  <svg width="800px" height="600px">
  <defs>
<filter id="distort">
  <feTurbulence baseFrequency=".015" type="fractalNoise"/>
  <feColorMatrix type="hueRotate" values="0">
    <animate attributeName="values" from="0" to="360" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  </feColorMatrix>
  <feDisplacementMap in="SourceGraphic" xChannelSelector="R" yChannelSelector="B" scale="20">
    <animate attributeName="scale" values="0;20;50;0" dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </feDisplacementMap>
  <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3"/>
  <feComponentTransfer result="main">
    <feFuncA type="gamma" amplitude="50" exponent="5"/>
  </feComponentTransfer>
  
  <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 
                                       0 0 0 0 0
                                       0 0 0 0 0
                                       0 0 0 1 0"/>
  <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="10"/>
  <feComposite operator="over" in="main"/>

</filter>
  </defs>
  <circle filter="url(#distort)" cx="200" cy="200" r="150" fill="red"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have once created a similar effect but not with filters. What I basically did was:

1. creating coordinates for a »star« shape, or a regular Polygon as array,
2. animate those coordinates, so that they moved, but not distorted the overall star shape too much,
3. used a [Catmul-Rom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centripetal_Catmull%E2%80%93Rom_spline) algorithm to smooth the edges and converted that result back to bezier path data and applied that to a `<path />`
4. Applied a gaussian blur on the resulting path